# Increment dates using loop value as they are added to a DataTable

Tags: datatable

--I am looping through one datatable with 4 columns; "Name", "StartDate", "EndDate", "numDays". 
--numDays is a calculated field created by subtracting "start" from "End".
--I want to end up with a datatable with 2 columns; "Name" and "Date", where if numdays = 3, then the name will be added on 3 different rows, one with the original start date, and the next two dates incremented by one date.
--I have the loop working fine using the numDay value for the "i <" value.
--I cannot figure out how to increment the date when the date is in parenthesis.
--Can anyone help? Apologies if I've left out data, please let me know what else you need to know. Thank you!

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtResult.Rows)
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(dtResult.Rows[0][3]); i++)
    {
     Final.Rows.Add(dr["Name"],dr["Start"]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish this on one line, I had to change my strategy and accomplish it on multiple lines

```
Final.Rows.Add(dr["Name"],dr["Start"]);
DateTime oldVal = Convert.ToDateTime( dr["Start"].ToString());
DateTime newVal = oldVal.AddDays(1);
dr["Start"] = newVal;
```